# How to attach username at the end of url?

Tags: uri

Suppose I have a site www.example.com with many users in it. Now user "abc" is logged in, then the username should be attached at the end of that URL, like: www.example.com/abc

Also I have fix content on my website e.g. about us , contact us etc.
Now if I go to the "about us" content then the link should be : www.example.com/abc/contact-us

Comment: Out of interest, why would you want something like this? And what should happen if user "john" clicks on the link (e.g. in an external forum) to `example.com/alice/contact-us`?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

go here: admin/config/search/path/patterns

and add: /[user:name]

to your replacement patterns.

Comment: thank you for suggestion but this works only for one user i.e. admin. But whenever i log in with other user, the url is same as admin. i want something like subsite, but only in single site.

Comment: Take a look at the other replacement pattern options.  It might be something like [currentuser:name]   

the one I gave you might be for the author of the node.

Comment: Just to make it clear to who reads this answer: admin/config/search/path/patterns is the setting page used by the [Pathauto](http://drupal.org/project/pathauto) module. Drupal core doesn't use tokens for defining path aliases.